# how to add inline style in a tag?

Tags: css, reactjs

How to add inline style in this given code? I just want to add an extra style when `sideListMenu === 'addNoteMenu'`
Here is my code..

```
 <div className="dashboard-side-list-menu_content">
                    {sideListMenu === 'additionMenu' && <DashboardAdditionMenu onHideSideListMenu={onHideSideListMenu} onShowSideListMenu={onShowSideListMenu} patientDetails={patientDetails} />}
                    {sideListMenu === 'actionMenu' && <DashboardActionMenu onHideSideListMenu={onHideSideListMenu} onShowSideListMenu={onShowSideListMenu} patientDetails={patientDetails}/>}
                    {sideListMenu === 'addPatientMenu' && <DashboardAddPatient onHideSideListMenu={onHideSideListMenu} />}
                    {(sideListMenu === 'addInsuranceMenu' && patientId) && <DashboardAddInsuranceMenu onHideSideListMenu={onHideSideListMenu} patientId={patientDetails.PatientNotesDocsModel.PatientInfo.PatientID} patientDetails={patientDetails}/>}
                    {(sideListMenu === 'addDocumentMenu' && patientId) && <DashboardAddDocumentMenu onHideSideListMenu={onHideSideListMenu} patientId={patientDetails.PatientNotesDocsModel.PatientInfo.PatientID} />}
                    {(sideListMenu === 'addNoteMenu' && patientId) && <DashboardAddNoteMenu onHideSideListMenu={onHideSideListMenu} patientId={patientDetails.PatientNotesDocsModel.PatientInfo.PatientID} />}
</div>
```

Comment: looks like you are using React. If yes, You can pass the css class name as a prop to the `<DashboardActionMenu>` component and use it inside the component. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: thankyou @GurtejSingh

Answer (score 0):

Inline styles can be given to a Tag using:

```
<div style={{color: 'red', fontSize: '20px'}}>Hello There!!</div>
```

If you are looking to add a style conditionally,

pass the style via props based on your condition.

Comment: no i don't mean thi.. How to apply that style for a particular tag between that div

Comment: @Levina can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use internal style

```
DashboardAdditionMenu{
    /*Your style here*/
}
DashboardActionMenu {
    /*Your style here*/
}
```